# To Finish the launch created in the report portal from the Jenkins pipeline (Post build action)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, reportportal

I have used the curl command to finish the launch with the launch id from the report portal and tried executing in bash. To use this in jenkins pipeline.

It returns :
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0

Curl command:

curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer API_Token" http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/:8080/api/v1/launch/701/finish

does this work or anything needs to be changed in syntax.

Comment: it should work in the same way from pipeline. ps GET looks weird, usually uses POST

Answer (score 0):

There is dedicated API endpoint for finish:
[image]

This is an example of payload you would need to send:

```json
{
  "attributes": [
    {
      "key": "string",
      "system": false,
      "value": "string"
    }
  ],
  "description": "string",
  "endTime": "2024-03-09T15:55:01.427Z",
  "status": "PASSED"
}
```

Not all of the fields are mandatory, please refer to Swagger/OpenAPI documentation that lives at http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:8080/ui/#api
Please, notice the method is 'PUT'.